# Not a group by expression : error

Tags: sql, select, hana

I want to query on a table keeping few fields as disctict. So, I use group by on the fields to be distinct. BUt HANA system throws an error: Not A Group By expression

```
select "REFID", "ORGID_WE", "ARTIKLE", "ORGID", "HELLER", "WERT", "BZBAS_AW" 
from "SYSTEM"."SOFT"
GROUP BY "REFID", "ORGID_WE", "ARTIKLE", "ORGID", "HELLER" ;
```

For me this looks good. Any ideas??

Comment: Removed the MySQL tag because MySQL does not generate this error.  I removed the SQL Server tag because it is also not about SQL Server.

Comment: This is basically SAP HANA. But i thought any guys with well verse knowledge on SQL might give some idea :)

Comment: What are you missing about the error message?  You have the columns `WERT` and `BSBAS_AW` in the `select` list, but they are not in aggregation functions (`min()`, `max()`, etc.) and they are not in the `group by`.

Comment: ERROR      claims/model1/claims.procedure
           Error creating procedure;not a GROUP BY expression: 'SOFT.WERT': line 7 col 87 (at pos 429) at ptime/query/checker/check_expr.cc:7085

ERROR      claims/model1/claims.procedure
           Object potentially broken due to transaction rollback.

ERROR                 exception 40177:
repository/base/activation/activator.cpp:835
Object potentially broken due to transaction rollback.

Comment: This is the error thrown!!

Comment: It's not a "group by" expression.  "group by" is used against aggregate queries.  Maybe you meant to use "order by"?

Comment: I understood that group by is nothing but the altenative for distinct. Isn't that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using aggregate functions:

```
select "REFID", "ORGID_WE", "ARTIKLE", "ORGID", "HELLER", sum("WERT"), sum("BZBAS_AW")
from "SYSTEM"."SOFT"
GROUP BY "REFID", "ORGID_WE", "ARTIKLE", "ORGID", "HELLER" ;
```

Comment: That works. BUt could you please tell me why you used sum in there just to make myself clear about my understanding!!

Comment: `sum()` is just arbitrary. you may as well use any aggregate function. the thing is when you group by `"REFID", "ORGID_WE", "ARTIKLE", "ORGID", "HELLER"`, the combination of those in the result set are made unique. this may lead to duplicates of `"WERT"` and `"BZBAS_AW"`, which need to be aggregated. you can choose to sum them, average them, take the max or min, count them. see here for more detailed explanations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function